# Instance member cannot be used on type Array

Tags: arrays, swift, function, class, search

I have the below class and I use a function math to search the string in both SongTitle and in ESongTitle.

```
class KeerthanaiArray: NSObject {
var SongTitle: String = String()
var SongLyrics: String = String()
var ESongTitle: String = String()

init(SongTitle: String, SongLyrics:String, ESongTitle: String) {
    self.SongTitle = SongTitle
    self.SongLyrics = SongLyrics
    self.ESongTitle = ESongTitle
}

class    func match(string:String) -> Bool {
    return SongTitle.containsString(string) || ESongTitle.containsString(string)
}
}
```

I get the error message 'Instance member SongTitle cannot be used on type 'Keerthanaiarray'. Please help

I need to declare the math func as class as I need to use the math function outside of its class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

1. This class `KeerthanaiArray` is not an array (as suggested by the name instead)
2. Why are you extending `NSObject`?
3. The class method `match` makes no sense, it is using 2 properties (`SongTitle` and `ESongTitle`) that does not exists in this context because they belongs to an **instance** of the class.

So let's cleanup your code

```
struct Song {
    let title: String
    let lyrics: String
    let eTitle: String

    func match(keyword: String) -> Bool {
        return title.containsString(keyword) || eTitle.containsString(keyword)
    }
}
```

> I make you class a struct because makes more sense. You are free to turn back to class. If you stay on structs please keep in mind they are value types.

Now given a list of `Song(s)`

```
let songs: [Song] = ...
```

and a keyword

```
let keyword = "The Great Gig In the Sky"
```

this is how we search the array

```
let results = songs.filter { $0.match(keyword) }
```

### Case insensitive version

```
struct Song {
    let title: String
    let lyrics: String
    let eTitle: String

    func match(keyword: String) -> Bool {
        let lowerCaseKeyword = keyword.lowercaseString
        return title.lowercaseString.containsString(lowerCaseKeyword) || eTitle.lowercaseString.containsString(lowerCaseKeyword)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to show the filtered result(basically I want to list the title after the string was matched between title & etitle) in the tableview.  I need to code logic in the func filterContentForSearchText to show the filtered result.  Could you please guide me on this

Comment: @Jebus: I answered your question, now please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have more questions you should create a new post.

Comment: `      self.searchResults = keerthanaiArray.filter({($0.match(searchText)) -> Bool in        
            return keerthanaiArray.SongTitle.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)`

Comment: I am trying something like this.. to filter and display the SongTitle in the function filterContentForSearch.  But I am not successful :(

Comment: @Jebus: I added the code for the case insensitive search

Comment: Hi, I have changed the declaration to struct now, but how exactly I can store list of songs in that array. Can I store something like this

Comment: Songs = [Song(SongTitle : songTitleT!, SongLyrics : songLyricsT!,
                        ESongTitle : EsongTitleT!)]    where songTitleT!, songLyricsT! and ESongTitlteT! are the values I retrieved from a sqlite database